# Ja Serializer task not found by Mix

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm playing with Phoenix but for some reason I'm not able to use JA_Serializer.

I have the dependency on my mix.exs

```
defp deps do
  (...)
  {:ja_serializer, "~> 0.11.1"},
  (...)
end
```

I followed the documentation:

My `config.exs`

```
config :phoenix, :format_encoders,
  "json-api": Poison

config :mime, :types, %{
  "application/vnd.api+json" => ["json-api"]
}
```

And re-compile mime:

```
mix deps.clean mime --build
mix deps.get
```

But it keeps failing:

```
$ mix ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api Market markets name:string phone:string
** (Mix) The task "ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api" could not be found
```

Comment: What if you run `mix compile` and then `mix ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api ...`?

Comment: I had to delete the *_build* folder and then recompile everything (OS: Windows)

Comment: FWIW neither removing `_build` nor compiling fixed this for me, but this worked `mix deps.compile phoenix`, `mix deps.clean ja_serializer`, `mix deps.get && mix deps.compile`. From https://github.com/vt-elixir/ja_serializer/issues/220#issuecomment-279242174